# RxJava Zip Operator Error Handling with Iterator

Tags: android, rx-java

**Background**

I have a process that uses RxJava to get data from different locations based on a list. Each item is got through a different method (all returning Observables.). Due to having N items to get the logic operator to use is `zip` with an iterator.

**The Problem**

The code below works as expected but it seems "wrong" that I need a `try-catch` block to catch the Exception that is thrown by `getBigFoo()` - that returns a `FooNotFoundException`. Do not the other error related operators cover this, such as `onErrorResumeNext()` and `onErrorReturn()`?

```
private Observable<Bar> processFoos(List<Foo> foos) {

        List<Observable<? extends IBar>> observablesToZip = new ArrayList<>();

        for(Foo foo : foos) {

            switch (foo.getType()) {

                case BIG_FOO :

                    try {
                        observablesToZip.add(getBigFoo(foo.getId()));
                    } catch (Exception exception) {
                        //do nothing - but this seems wrong
                    }
            }
        }

        return Observable.zip(observablesToZip, results -> mergeFoosIntoBar(results));
    }
```

**Attempts Made**

The attempt below doesn't seem to catch the Exception generated. I don't understand why as there are technically no upstream or downstream items in the sequence, so `Observable.empty()` should work?

```
private Observable<Bar> processFoos(List<Foo> foos) {

        List<Observable<? extends IBar>> observablesToZip = new ArrayList<>();

        for(Foo foo : foos) {

            switch (foo.getType()) {

                case BIG_FOO :
                   observablesToZip.add(getBigFoo(foo.getId().onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty()));
            }
        }

        return Observable.zip(observablesToZip, results -> mergeFoosIntoBar(results));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@dwursteisen was on to the right answer, but wasn't quite there.

My issue was that I was throwing a new FooNotFoundException:

```
throw new FooNotFoundException()
```

But what I needed to do was:

```
return Observable.error(new FooNotFoundException());
```

Then in my Zip function:

```
observablesToZip.add(getBigFoo(foo.getId())).onExceptionResumeNext(Observable.just(null);
```

Using the above combination means that the overall sequence does not abort and return an error when the individual Observables are resolved and potentially throw errors.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use `defer`. `getBigFoo` should not throw an exception but instead return an `Observable` in error. So `defer` may help you to fix it :

```
Observable<IBar> obs = Observable.defer(() -> {
             try {
                 return getBigFoo(foo.getId());
              } catch (Exception ex) {
                  return Observable.error(ex);
              } 
});
observablestoZip.add(obs);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, doesn't this push the issue elsewhere. I may well need defer however if getBigFoo either returns Observable.just(foo) or Observable.error(new FooNotFoundException()) then wouldn't the error operators catch this?

Comment: if getBigFoo don't throw any exception, but instead returning an Observable (Observable.just() or Observable.error()) then defer is useless. I use defer here only to mimic what getBigFoo, in my opinion, should do (ie: not throwning any exception).

Comment: OK - so pretend getBigFoo returns Observable.error() how can I catch it without the try-catch block?

Comment: You can't (catch it) You'll be notified thanks to your subscriber. Or you'll have to manage it using onErrorResumeNext, ... methods.

Comment: So something like getBigFoo(id).onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty());

Comment: Yup. But I don't know how the zip operator will manage this empty observable. You may have to emit a value (like null). Otherwise zip may block your Observable

Comment: Can we move this to chat for a few minutes?

Answer (score 0):

Could you make getBigFoo(foo.getId()) throw RuntimeException instead Exception?. All Exceptions on Pipeline must be captured, but not runtimeExceptions.

Take a look to this silly example

```
         /**
 * Here is a silly example how runtimeExceptions are not needed
 */
@Test
public void observableRuntimeException() {
    Integer[] numbers = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    Observable.from(numbers)
              .doOnNext(number -> throwRuntimeException())
              .doOnError(t -> System.out.println("Expecting illegal argument exception:" + t.getMessage()))
              .subscribe();

}

private void throwRuntimeException() {
    throw new RuntimeException();
}
```

you can see more examples here  https://github.com/politrons/reactive

Comment: 'FooNotFoundException extends IllegalArgumentException' could be updated to extend `RuntimeException` - will give it a go.

Comment: Just tried this, no dice. The exception is not caught by doOnError and the process blows up. Nice idea though.